# Inverse Fourier Transform the given transfer function

Tags: fourier-transform

Given
$$X(f)=\frac{2}{(1+j2\pi f)^3}$$
so,
$$X^*(f)=\frac{2}{(1-j2\pi f)^3}$$
and a transfer function:
$$H(f)=\frac{2(2\pi f)^2 e^{-j2\pi ft}}{(1-j2\pi f)^3}$$
With the following conversion formula:
$$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)=Ft^{-1}[(j2\pi f)^nF(f)]$$

What I got is:
$$\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(-t)$$

Yet the answer is:
$$-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(-t)$$

**I don't understand where does the minus sign come from**. I didn't learn fourier transfer properly but the course I am taking asks us to look up the table if we aren't familiar with fourier transform.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. I need to add an extra j in $H(f)$, such that
$$H(f)=\frac{2(-1)(j2\pi f)^2 e^{-j2\pi ft}}{(1-j2\pi f)^3}$$
Hence, the extra terms will remains after transformation. 
$$-\frac{d^2}{dt^2}x(-t)$$